# DOMNode to DOMElement in php

Tags: php, xml, dom

I want to convert a `DOMNode` object from a call to `getElementsByTagName()` to a `DOMElement` in order to access methods like `getElementsByTagName()` on the child element. In any other language, I would cast and it would be easy, but after some quick looking, PHP does not have object casting. So what I need to know is how to get a `DOMElement` object from a `DOMNode` object.

Comment: Did you check if getElementsByTagName() actually returns DOMElement objects with something like if($item instanceof DOMElement)? If it is you don't need to cast, you can just use $item like it is a DOMElement

Comment: getElementsByTagName() returns a DOMNodeList, i did assume that a DOMNodeList was a list of DOMNode. the reason i thought you had to cast was because i had to cast in java when i wanted to do the same process.

Comment: The funny thing is that getElementById returns DOMElement but getElementsByTagName returns a list where each item is DOMNode !!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to cast anything, just call the method:

```
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $spans = $link->getElementsByTagName('span');
}
```

And by the way, `DOMElement` is a subclass of `DOMNode`. If you were talking about a `DOMNodeList`, then accessing the elements in such a list can be done, be either the method presented above, with a `foreach()` loop, either by using the `item()` method of `DOMNodeList`:

```
$link_0 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0);
```

Comment: Does a DOMNodeList ever return a DOMNode that isn't a DOMElement? [The docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) just say DOMNode and don't mention DOMElement. For example, what if the DOMNodeList comes from [DOMXPath::query](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)?

Comment: @user2016290 yeah, `DOMXPath::query` or even `DOMNode::childNodes`. https://gist.github.com/igstan/9654eca0db804c8e87bd

Comment: DOMElement has extra methods, which aren't available in DOMNode. For example getAttribute (). And although if you use this method on a DOMNode, it will work in PHP, it won't work with your IDE (not available in the  pop-up methods list). So the question stands: how to get DOMElement from getElementsByTagName

Comment: @Andrew `getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList` of `DOMElement`, that's why it's called get *elements*. So it's always safe to call `DOMElement` methods on that list's items. If an IDE can't handle this... that's a separate issue. PHP is not Java, we should treat them accordingly or switch languages.

Comment: @Ionuț G. Stan do you have some reference material in the PHP manual which would say that DOMNodeList contains DOMElement(s) and _not_ DOMNode(s)? The manual says that there is just DOMNodeList returned without any more info what exactly is inside this list. Default assumption is that it's a DOMNode, but i am missing anything mentioned about DOMElement

Comment: @Andrew a `DOMNodeList`, in general, contains `DOMNode`s, yes. But the `DOMNodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName` only contains `DOMElement`s. Although it's not emphasized, the docs for that method say this: "This function returns a new instance of class DOMNodeList containing all the __elements__ with a given local tag name.". You can also verify using this little script: https://gist.github.com/igstan/9654eca0db804c8e87bd.

Comment: @Andrew I understand the frustration that the IDE would complain about this, but IMHO this is outside the scope of PHP the language.

Comment: @Ionuț G. Stan no frustration regarding IDE, it's fixable. I just wanted to know PHP (officialy) behaves, so IDE could be adjusted to function properly.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use in my project to minimize IDE warning.

```
/**
 * Cast a DOMNode into a DOMElement
 */
    function cast_e(DOMNode $node) : DOMElement {
    if ($node) {
        if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            return $node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any explicit typecasting, just check if your DOMNode object has a nodeType of `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`.

PHP will be perfectly happy with this.

If you use [PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint) to check your code you will notice that PHPLint complains about using `getElementsByTagName` on a DOMNode object. To get around this you need to jump through the following hoop:

```
/*.object.*/ $obj = $node;
$element = /*.(DOMElement).*/ $obj;
```

Then you will have a $element variable of the correct type and no complaints from PHPLint.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is mostly an annoying IDE problem.

The reason is `$DOMNodeList->item(0)` witch returns a DOMNode ( or at least the IDE thinks so ).

To fix this you will have to Extract out the `$DOMDocument->getElementsByTagName( $tagName )->item($index)` into a method of its own. In the DOCBlock you set the @return statement to DOMElement witch fixes the inspection problem.

This Works at least in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a more elegant solution in **IntelliJ/PHPStorm**. I managed to solve the issue like this:

```
    private function doSomething(DOMNode $child){
        
        if(!$child instanceof DOMElement)
            throw new Exception('DOMElement expected but got something else.');
        
        $attr = $child->getAttribute('attr'); //recognized by PHPStorm now as DOMElement
        
        /* and more code */
        
    }
```

All my code corretly assumes DOMNode which is de super class of DOMElement but also DOMComment etc. When I need DOMElement to use `getAttribute` for example, then I add above check.