# Dom Node for PHP find href attribute issue

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to pull the href from a url from some data using php's domDocument.

The following pulls the anchor for the url, but I want the url

```
$events[$i]['race_1'] = trim($cols->item(1)->nodeValue);
```

Here is more of the code if it helps.

```
   // initialize loop
   $i = 0;
   // new dom object  
   $dom = new DOMDocument();  

   //load the html  
   $html = @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);  
   //discard white space   
   $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;   

   //the table by its tag name  
   $information = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
   $rows = $information->item(4)->getElementsByTagName('tr');  

   foreach ($rows as $row)   
   { 
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');   
    $events[$i]['title'] = trim($cols->item(0)->nodeValue); 
    $events[$i]['race_1'] = trim($cols->item(1)->nodeValue);   
$events[$i]['race_2'] = trim($cols->item(2)->nodeValue);  
$events[$i]['race_3'] = trim($cols->item(3)->nodeValue);
$date = explode('/', trim($cols->item(4)->nodeValue));
$events[$i]['month'] = $date['0'];
$events[$i]['day'] = $date['1'];
$citystate = explode(',', trim($cols->item(5)->nodeValue));   
$events[$i]['city'] = $citystate['0'];
$events[$i]['state'] = $citystate['1'];
$i++;
   }
   print_r($events);
```

Here is the contents of the TD tag

> ```
> <td width="12%" align="center" height="13"><!--mstheme--><font face="Arial"><span lang="en-us"><b>
>           <font style="font-size: 9pt;" face="Verdana">
>           <a linkindex="18" target="_blank" href="results2010/brmc5k10.htm">Overall</a>
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update, I see the issue. You need to get the list of `a` elements from the `td`.

```
$cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
// $cols->item(1) is a td DOMElement, so have to find anchors in the td element
// then get the first (only) ancher's href attribute
// (chaining looks long, might want to refactor/check for nulls)
$events[$i]['race_1'] = trim($cols->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

---

Pretty sure that you should be able to call [`getAttribute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) on the item. You can verify that the item is nodeType `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`; it will return an empty string if the item isn't a DOMElement.

```
<?php
// ...
$events[$i]['race_1'] = trim($cols->item(1)->getAttribute('href'));
// ...   
?>
```

See related: [DOMNode to DOMElement in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994102/domnode-to-domelement-in-php)

Comment: This returns an empty string but I don't understand why,  I have added the contents of the TD tag above to maybe help

Comment: It's probably because `$cols->item(1)` isn't a DOMElement. Do a `var_dump($cols->item(1)->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE);` to see if it is.