# Using regexp to get all href links except the base href

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I am trying get all html links within a string and replace them using preg_replace to another link (for link tracking etc)

It works fine on links like http://www.facebook.com but not those that do not have a 'www' within the string.
So the first URL would be fine, but the latter wouldn't work - can anyone suggest how I alter my expression to allow BOTH links like this to work.

```
http://www.twitter.com
http://twitter.com/myusername

$message = preg_replace("/<a([^>]+)href=\"http\:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/*)?)/", "<a$1href=\"http://www.site.com/system/link_tracker.php?URL=$2&ID={$ID}\"", $message);
```

Comment: why don't you get everything between `href="` and the closing (first occurence of after previous pattern) `"` ?

Comment: i've just grabbed the preg_replace from another page - how would i do this?

Comment: I have put a link to the regExp - this expression works on this website but not when I put this within the preg_replace any ideas?
http://regexr.com?30hkc

$message = preg_replace("<a([^>]+)(?<=href\=")[^]+?(?=")", "<a$1href=\"http://www.site.com/system/link_tracker.php?URL=$2&ID={$ID}", $message);

I get this :- parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: it seems the enclosing / or whatever symbol you want to use is missing; the `<` becomes the start the regex part, and it ends at `>` so that the next `]` is not seen. Maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/*)

This is by no means a URL regex. It might work for two or three cases, but you ignore the existence of:

- [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure),
- [multiple labels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names) in the domain name (foo15.cdn.amazon.com),
- dashes in the domain name,
- [Internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name),
- TLDs existing of other than 2 or 3 letters (.info, .museum) or multiple parts (.co.uk) and most importantly
- deep links.

Users will especially not like the latter, because when they deeplink to some site, this link is rendered invalid using your regex. Use a common way, for example [`DOMDocument.replaceChild()`](http://at.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) to alter links in an HTML document (which I assume you use, since you're capturing URL's in `<a>` tags).

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667358/266143), that can be done with something like this, not tested:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$html = @$dom->load(...); // Load your html
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); 

foreach ($links as $link)
{
    // Store original node
    $origLink = $link;

    // Find original href
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');

    // Replace link
    $href = "http://www.site.com/system/link_tracker.php?URL=" . urlencode($href) . "&ID={$ID}";

    // Replace href
    $link->setAttribute('href', $href);

    // Replace child (don't know if this is required because you already alter $link)
    $dom->replaceChild($link, $origLink);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = preg_replace("/<a([^>]+)href=\"http\:\/\/((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/*)?)/", "<a$1href=\"http://www.site.com/system/link_tracker.php?URL=$2&ID={$ID}\"", $message);
```

Will work on http://twitter.com and http://www.abcd.gov.edu.ua.sub.sub.domain.com

Comment: Thanks - that seems to return the following error :(

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset

Answer (score 0):

As regular expression I would try with the following:

```
/<a([^>]+href=\"http:\/\/([^\"]+?)\"/
```

This will grab everything given as href "argument" iff the (x)html href is contained between double quotes. For the purpose of using that as part of another URL, you would like to encode character like ? and & to avoid they be interpreted as part of your URL